# Apache 2.4 with PHP 5.4: no mysql available

Tags: php, mysql, apache, installation

I've set up an Apache 2.4 HTTP Server with PHP 5.4 and MySQL 5.5 on my Windows 7 x64 machine.

Everything works fine, except that in PHP only the "mysqlnd" is loaded. mysql and mysqli are missing. The entries in the php.ini are available and active. The PATH variable is appended to the directory of the mysql binary files (libmysql.dll).

There are no entries about warnings or errors in the error.log of Apache 2.4

Does someone have an idea?

Comment: is mysql listed when you run phpinfo() ?

Comment: Do you have more than one instance of PHP installed?

Comment: No, I'm running only one instance. (PHP 5.4.3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same troubles yesterday, after settig up Apache 2.2 and PHP 5.4.6 on my Windows 7 64-bit machine. I resolved this with the following changes in the php.ini:

1. Setting the extension_dir to (your-php-path)\ext.

   ```
   extension_dir = "c:\progra~2\php546\ext"
   ```

   You can avoid the whitespaces in the foldername Program Files (x86) when you use the 8.3 version of the foldername. You can get it with the following command:

   ```
   dir \prog* /x
   ```
2. Enable the wanted MySQL module(s).

   ```
   extension=php_mysql.dll
   extension=php_mysqli.dll
   ...
   extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
   ```
3. Restart Apache Web Server.

   ```
   for %s in (stop start) do net %s apache2.2
   ```

   You can also use the Apache Monitor or the Services to restart it.